# Cannot join domain window 2016 for ubuntu 22.04.3 lts

Tags: 22.04, domain-server

I have an Active Directory setup on a virtual machine on Windows Server 2016. I'm trying to join an Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS virtual machine to that AD.  I follow https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_22.04&p=realmd. I can discover the AD with realm but cannot join the AD. I captured the packet and got the error as shown in the red box:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you circled is not the error. KRB_ERR_RESPONSE_TOO_BIG just tells the client and server to switch from UDP to TCP. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/kerberos-protocol-registry-kdc-configuration-keys You need to find the actual error, perhaps in `journalctl -r`

Comment: Deleting the information from your question does not hide it from the internet. If there was any sensitive information, you should change your password. We need to leave the information up for future readers with the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You need to type the realm name in uppercase](https://serverfault.com/a/1010379/987638):

```bash
realm join -U quantri_tthieu@VCBS.COM vcbs.com -v
```

Comment: Thank Daniel T. I can join AD successful but i cann't login with domain account. why i need to type the realm name in uppercase

Comment: @Hieutrung The upper case realm name is a convention that a Kerberos service is configured to require for pure functionality troubleshooting issue to differentiate problems with the Kerberos service from problems with the DNS issues  ... That convention became the standard with time ... That's why ... And you need to make sure an active directory username is passed to Kerberos with the realm part as uppercase for that user to be able to authenticate as well.

Comment: @Hieutrung Please ask another question about login because this question's title is about joining

Comment: thank you Raffa and Daniel T